# RenderPlot returns invisible plot on my local machine, but it is visible on other machines

Tags: r, shiny

Obligatory "I'm very new to R/Shiny". I am in the process of building an app which simply queries a database, and returns the plot of the data retrieved. Here is the generalised code that is being used to return the plot:

**App.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library("RODBC")
library(ggplot2)

ui <- mainPanel(fluidPage(
      tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot1"))
              )
           ))

server <- function(input, output,session) {

       db <- odbcConnect(dsn="db", uid = "username", pwd = "password",believeNRows=FALSE )

       plotQueryTxt = paste("SELECT * FROM myTable")

       myData <- sqlQuery(db, plotQueryTxt )

       odbcClose(db)

       output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ggplot(myData,aes(COLUMN1,COLUMN2))+ geom_point()})
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The issue here is that, on my personal machine, the plot is rendered but is invisible. When this app is run on other machines, or on a remote server, the plot can be seen. My question is: **what is causing the plot to be visible on one machine, and not on another?** Is it an issue with my graphics card, or something along those lines?

I have checked all my R packages are up to date, so I don't think that's the issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: is the data available on other machines? Maybe add `print(myData)` in the `renderPlot` and look in your R console if you see the data, or make a test dataframe in the server instead of getting it fron an sql database to see if the plot shows on all machines.

Comment: Yes, the data is available on all machines. If I change the renderPlot to a renderTable for example, the table is correctly output on all machines. The same goes for the print(myData). It's only when I ask it to produce a visual plot that it fails to show.